# filepicker.io mimetype audio in firefox

Tags: firefox, mime-types, filepicker.io

The mimetype settings look like this:

```
  mimetypes: ['audio/*'],
```

Firefox on windows 7 cannot upload mp3 files, other browsers work fine. They get the "not audio file" error.

Is this a bug with filepicker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely this is an issue with the way that firefox is reporting the mimetypes of mp3 files - I'd recommend trying filtering by extension instead. There are times when mimetypes are more appropriate and times where they break down due to differing implementations, which is why we provide both mechanisms.